# Send users to a pre-filled Amazon cart checkout

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, e-commerce

I'm working on a site that will create pre-set packages of items. To start, I'm using Amazon to test the idea, pulling some affiliate sales, and then I'll fulfill orders myself if the idea deems successful.

My goal is to have a "buy now" type button, and upon clicking, the user will arrive at an Amazon checkout now page, with a cart pre-filled with items of my choosing, and my affiliate number.

I'm a PHP developer, so if a solution must be language specific, that's the language to go with. If it's more of a conceptual answer, or if there's an API for this, that works too.

Comment: Don't do that. If a random size was able to add stuff to my Amazon card, I'd report a cross-site security problem to Amazon.

Comment: I don't want to force a sale, just send them to the cart with some items already in it.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your comment as card, as in a credit card, not cart. Is that what you meant?

Comment: you could use the Lists feature, and link to those lists.

Comment: I want to ask if there is a way to send different size/color parameter? E.g. www.amazon.com/Hanes-10Ankle-White-10-13/dp/B008H2ETCI/ref=sr_1_sc_2?s=sporting-goods&ie=UTF8&qid=1381957831&sr=1-2-spell&keywords=white+socsk can I send white  socks to the cart?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You may use link that contains ASINs and their quantity. It doesn't add items to someone's cart but confirms to add to cart.

```
URL:
http://www.amazon.com/gp/aws/cart/add.html

Parameters:
- AssociateTag
- ASIN.<number>        <number> starts at 1
- Quantity.<number>    one quantity parameter for each ASIN parameter

Example (parameters separated by line break for visibility):
http://www.amazon.com/gp/aws/cart/add.html
    ?AssociateTag=your-tag
    &ASIN.1=B003IXYJYO
    &Quantity.1=2
    &ASIN.2=B0002KR8J4
    &Quantity.2=1
    &ASIN.3=B0002ZP18E
    &Quantity.3=1
    &ASIN.4=B0002ZP3ZA
    &Quantity.4=2
```

One line example: https://www.amazon.com/gp/aws/cart/add.html?AssociateTag=your-tag&ASIN.1=B003IXYJYO&Quantity.1=2&ASIN.2=B0002KR8J4&Quantity.2=1&ASIN.3=B0002ZP18E&Quantity.3=1&ASIN.4=B0002ZP3ZA&Quantity.4=2&ASIN.5=B004J2JG6O&Quantity.5=1

ASINs are found in the product's page URL or by searching for "ASIN" on the product page. [More details here](https://www.amazon.ca/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=200576730)

Comment: How do you generate these links? Is there any API or reference?

Comment: See [Amazon Product Advertising API Best Practices](https://aws.amazon.com/articles/1057) for help locating your Associate Tag.

Comment: I know for sure there is the way to add a coupon code in the url for at least one ASIN. Does anybody know how?

Answer (score 0):

Amazon does not allow you to add items to someone's cart.  They require that the user making the purchase click the add to cart button.

The best you can do for this is to create a Listmania! list with the items.  You can see more details about how to do that [here](http://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?ie=UTF8&nodeId=14279651).

You then need to make an affiliate link to the list, and instruct the user to click the 'Add all Items to Cart' button at the bottom of the list.

Unfortunately, there is no way to make this take less clicks for the user since Amazon does not want users accidentally purchasing items they did not want.